# How to change in postgresql password of the user using SQL

Tags: sql, password, postgresql

How to change in postgresql password of the user using SQL.
I have user (alex) and his password (e.g. pass) 
i need to change using sql statement his password to NULL...

Answer (score 26):

The syntax for changing a user's password is

```
ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Answer (score 6):

You want

```
ALTER ROLE alex SET PASSWORD TO NULL
```

You will of course have to do this as a Postgres superuser.

Unfortunately, that doesn't let you log in with a blank password.  You can only log in without a password if your pg_hba.conf entry specifies an auth type of 'trust' instead of 'md5' or 'password'.

So this SQL command is just cleaning up the password for a user that used to have one, but who is now trusted to get in without a password.  You can't actually authenticate with a blank password.  The distinction is slight.